# Capture output of table_print

Tags: ruby

`table_print` is a gem to format your strings in a table.

I would like to capture the output of `table_print` in a variable to eventually write it to a file.

Taking the below string:

```
my_string_data = [
   {'header1' => 'elem1', 'header2' => 'elem2', 'header3' => 'elem3'},
   {'header1' => 'elem1', 'header2' => 'elem2', 'header3' => 'elem3'}
]
```

I can print it nicely with `table_print`:

```
tp my_string_data
HEADER1 | HEADER2 | HEADER3
--------|---------|--------
elem1   | elem2   | elem3
elem1   | elem2   | elem3
=> 0.00036
```

However I can't seem to be able to capture the output because `tp` actually returns a `float`:

```
tp_output = tp my_string_data
HEADER1 | HEADER2 | HEADER3
--------|---------|--------
elem1   | elem2   | elem3
elem1   | elem2   | elem3
=> 0.000367

tp_output
=> 0.000367
```

Is there a way to return the string, not the float, so that I can have a variable containing my string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create an instance of `TablePrint::Printer` as in the accepted answer. That class has a `table_print` static method that does the work for you:

```
data = [
  {'header1' => 'elem1', 'header2' => 'elem2', 'header3' => 'elem3'},
  {'header1' => 'elem1', 'header2' => 'elem2', 'header3' => 'elem3'}
]

str = TablePrint::Printer.table_print(data)

puts str
# => HEADER1 | HEADER2 | HEADER3
#    --------|---------|--------
#    elem1   | elem2   | elem3  
#    elem1   | elem2   | elem3
```

See it in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/CrimsonVibrantMath

Answer (score 2):

as of table_print gem version

you can do this:

```
table = TablePrint::Printer.new(my_string_data)
tp_output = table.table_print
puts tp_output
HEADER1 | HEADER2 | HEADER3
--------|---------|--------
elem1   | elem2   | elem3
elem1   | elem2   | elem3
```

Comment: The `"#{}"` around `table.table_print` here isn't doing anything. `#{}` is for string interpolation, but you're not interpolating _with_ anything. `puts table.table_print` is all you need here.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily redirect `STDOUT`.

```
str = <<_
# => HEADER1 | HEADER2 | HEADER3
#    --------|---------|--------
#    elem1   | elem2   | elem3  
#    elem1   | elem2   | elem3
_

io = StringIO.new
  #=> #<StringIO:0x0000557df4b227b8>
$stdout = io

puts str
$stdout = STDOUT

s = io.string.lines[1..-2]
puts s
# => HEADER1 | HEADER2 | HEADER3
#    --------|---------|--------
#    elem1   | elem2   | elem3  
#    elem1   | elem2   | elem3
```